# Is there any way to detect and change the input value format?

Tags: javascript

I am checking and validating the text area value with a regex
and I want to change the formating like this:
user input:

```
123456
```

change to:

```
12/34/56
```

can this be done in pure js?

edit:

this is what I did yet:

```
 function changeIt() {
  var inputChanger = document.getElementById("id").value.replace(something , something);
  document.getElementById("id").value = inputChanger;
}
```

but no idea how to proceed

Comment: yes it can be done, have you tried anything? show us your attempt

Comment: Just by that right there, you could test if it's a number.  Which the 2nd one is not.

Comment: There are lots of "input mask" plugins that will do this automatically for you.

Comment: `output = input.match(/\d{2}/g)` to split into chunk of 2 digits, then `output.join("/");` to join them together with slashes inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

*Note: for this code to work, the HTML must come before the JavaScript, but stack overflow apparently re-order's code snippets to always show the JS first (?)*

```js
var input = document.getElementById('my-input');

function format() {
  // \d matches a digit, 
  // parenthesis let you use the matched values as $n in the replacement string
  input.value = input.value.replace(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/, '$1/$2/$3');
}

// you probably only need one of these, but it doesn't hurt to have both
input.addEventListener('change', format);
input.addEventListener('keyup', format);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my-input" />
```

It can also, of course, be done with some jQuery and maybe a plugin like http://jquery-plugins.net/maskjs-jquery-plugin-to-mask-inputs - but I think it's good to understand what's happening under the hood even if you end up going that way.